# Jackson JSON key as value in Class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to use some of the keys in a JSON document as values in a class and I do not want to make use of Map.

I have got a JSON document with the following form:

```
{
"GateWay": {
  "API1": {
    "Infos": "More",
    "Meta": [1,2,3]
  },
  "API2": {
    "Infos": "Even more",
    "Meta": [4,5,6]
  },
  "API3": {
    "Infos": "Nope",
    "Meta": []
  }
}
```

I want this structure to be deserialized as a Java class like this:

```
class GateWays {
    List<GateWay> gateWays;
}

class GateWay {
    String name; // API1, API2 or API3 for example

    String infos;

    List<Integer> meta;
}
```

How do I tell Jackson to take the key as value in a class instead of using maps?

Comment: I do not think that I am breaking the JSON contract, the JSON comes as it is and I want to import it into a more convenient POJO structure without additional mapping for working with the imported data in my JAVA code.

Answer (score 0):

Try as following:

```
class Result{
   GateWay GateWay;

   //getter and setter
}

class GateWay {
   Api API1; // API1, API2 or API3 for example
   //getter and setter
}

class Api{
   String Infos;
   List<Integer> Meta;

  //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear enough, the keys are not fixed anc could even named like API1000 etc. …

Answer (score 0):

I am just considering below is your POST method...

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response YourPostMethod(@Context UriInfo info, GateWays gateways, @HeaderParam("your_header_porom") String yourheaderporom ......);
```

Now you need to declare two classes as below (One is inner class here)

```
   import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
   import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
   import java.io.Serializable;

  @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
  public class GateWays {
  List<GateWay> gateWays;

  public List<GateWay> setGateWays(){
    return this.gateWays;
  }
  public void setGateWays(ist<GateWay> gateWays){
        this.gateWays = gateWays;
  }

  @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
  public static class GateWay implements Serializable {
    String Name; // API1, API2 or API3 for example *** Here you need to change your json message to inject APIs into it like "Name" : "API1"
    String Infos;
    List<Integer> Meta; 
    //add your setter and getter methods here like I did in the above class     
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The JSON comes as it is, so I can not change the data structure.